# C: void* as handle, loses const expressiveness

Tags: c, pointers, constants, typedef, handle

I try to consider an API strategy where, in the header file, instead of

```
typedef struct {...} type_t;
extern void func(const type_t* instance);
```

I have

```
typedef void* type_t_handle;
extern void func(const type_t_handle instance);
```

But I find now that, while before I had options

```
const type_t* const x; // (1)
const type_t* x;       // (2)
type_t* const x;       // (3)
```

I now only have option (3) (I checked once I saw that writing `const type_t_handle const x;` results in a "duplicate ‘const’ declaration specifier" warning). In other words the `typedef` seems to "bind" the `*` and the base type and we can't "squeeze" a const in between anymore...

This means that the `const` in the parameter `const type_t_handle instance` is useless, I think - it will not result in a "passing argument ... discards ‘const’ qualifier"-type warning which will remind about intention of non-modification...

Is there some solution?

Comment: This is just one reason not to `typedef` a pointer.

Comment: Is your goal to obscure the fields of a structure?

Comment: @Irelia To have an abstract API returning handles, so that the user does not need to concentrate on what actually the objects constitute internally.

Comment: This is _not_ how you should do that. Hiding pointers behind a typedef is (as you recognized) very problematic for numerous reasons. Use opaque types instead: [How to do private encapsulation in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283888)

Comment: @Lundin Thanks, I already understood what you write in the link (you wrote it to me in one of my previous questions). But I now want, in the language of your link, to have struct cstring to simply be an alias for a struct from a different .h file, another library, and the user should not necessarily care or see that. Since I didn't see that you can do struct aliases (so that aliasing only occurs int the .c file, keeping the .h file clean from mention of the other library), I thought about trying an approach where you have void* handles.

Comment: @Sasha In that case you can do an opaque struct acting as a wrapper, with the other struct as its only member. You include "other.h" from your .c file so that it isn't exposed to the user by your h file. Void pointers are unfortunate for many reasons, particularly because of their non-existent type safety.

Comment: @Lundin Oh, that sounds like a nice idea, thank you very much, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that the `typedef` binds the pointer to the base type so you can't make the pointed-to type `const`.

You'll need to make a separate `typedef` for the `const` qualified version.

```
typedef void* type_t_handle;
typedef const void* const_type_t_handle;
```

On a side note, rather than using a `void *` for the type used by the API, instead use an opaque struct i.e. one that is declared in the header file but defined in the implementation file.

```
typedef struct xyz type_t;
extern void func(const type_t* instance);
```

This give better type safety than using a plain `void *`.

Comment: Thank you. The "problem" I have currently with opaque struct is that I can't alias a struct, only a type, and I have header1.h which defines structs/types, header2.h which defines structs/types, and I want the user to only "know" header2.h, but some of the types in header2.h I want to just alias some corresponding types from header1.h. I am not able to do it without "disclosing" the names from header1.h...